# Trouble with hover effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, computer-vision

to put it simply, I am trying to add a hover effect onto my cv.

I want when someone hovers over my linkedin icon, for it to display a text underneath saying "LinkedIn"
However I need this to be in Javascript.

html part `<a href="link" id="liIcon" target="_blank"><i class="icon-linkedin"></i></a>`

```
<div id="popup">LinkedIn</div>
```

js part

```
var e = document.getElementById('liIcon');

e.onmouseover = function() {
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block';
}

e.onmouseout = function() {
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
}
```

and css part

```
#popup {
    display:none;
  }
```

Any idea why it isn't working?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add it. It is there. I just forgot to post it.

Comment: What does your css linking look like? (the part where you add css to your html)

Comment: <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: try a slash at the start? (/css/main.css) because the code works, so your issue is probably something like this (Add it to a snippet in the question, you'll see it working)

Comment: No it isn't working for some reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed a few semicolons missing after the `onmouseover`s. I'm not an expert on JS, but an unterminated statement looks weird.

Also, I added a LinkedIn text to the button, cause there's no image link visible in the following code. This is how your code should be structured for your code to work (assuming your browser doesn't have JavaScript disabled):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #popup {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="link" id="liIcon" target="_blank"><i class="icon-linkedin">LinkedIn</i></a>
<div id="popup">LinkedIn</div>
<script>
    var e = document.getElementById('liIcon');

    e.onmouseover = function () {
        document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block';
    };

    e.onmouseout = function () {
        document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

No hover:

[image]

Hover:

[image]

Comment: Okay so it only worked after i took the javascript code inside the html code. But I don't understand why it won't call the javascript file i have...

Comment: what does the js link in your file look like?

Comment: <script src="js/scripts.js"></script> I've tried putting a slash. Didn't change anything.

Comment: No there aren't any.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes selectors can get fussy, I've run into issues with  tags nested in other elements similar to what you have here.

Have you tried adding an event listener to the icon tag as well?

```
var icon = document.getElementById('liIcon').getElementsByClassName('icon-linkedin');

// assuming there is only one element of class: icon-linkedin, access element by index 0
icon[0].onmouseover = function () {
  document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block';
};

icon[0].onmouseout = function () {
  document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
};
```

Comment: That didn't do it.